# Bison generated Parser exits before reading through entire file

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I have a BISON generated Parser for a subset of Verilog. I see that the parser jumps to the end of file before reading the entire file. I'm pasting a snippet of the Log from the parser and the file I am trying to parse.

```
   Stack now 0 1 6 10 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13
   Entering state 29
   Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 85(";")
   Next token is token SEMICOLON (design.v:1.207: )
   Shifting token SEMICOLON (design.v:1.207: )
   Entering state 13
   Reading a token: --accepting rule at line 100("0")
   Next token is token NUMBER (design.v:1.208: )
   Reducing stack by rule 12 (line 174):**
      $1 = token SEMICOLON (design.v:1.207: )
   -> $$ = nterm module_item_list (design.v:1.207: )
   Stack now 0 1 6 10 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29 13 29
   Entering state 44
   Reducing stack by rule 11 (line 172):
      $1 = token SEMICOLON (design.v:1.185: )
```

the piece of code that is being parsed is below

```
wire [3:0] z;
wire w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7;
not (z[0], a[0]);  
xnor (z[1], a[0], a[1]);
```

It fails at the end of "not();"

Any inputs appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, this line seems to be correct. Are you sure it doesn't fail because of some previous errors?

Comment: This is a Bison/yacc question, not a Verilog question. If you want any help, you need to post the relevant part of the parser and the error you're getting. Is this homework?

Comment: If that log is unedited, then your lexer seems to be reading `;` `0`, which does not appear consecutively in your input. So it may be a lexer issue, not a parser issue. What evidence do you have that the parser is "jumps to the end of the file"? Is the snippet you quote the end of the file? If so, your lexer is returning a `NUMBER` instead of an end of file mark, which also points at a lexer problem. It would be useful to see a bit of your `flex` rules.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks like the buffer being read by the Lexer is becoming null. I output the buffer for every token read .. and this is what it looks like..

```
    nor (z[3], w2, w3);
    nor (w4, sel, z[3]);
    nor (w5, sel, z[2]);
    and (w6, sel, z[1]);
    and (w7, sel, z[0]);
    or (out[1], w4, w6);
    or (out[0], w5, w7);
    endmodule

And 
  *yy_cp]
Let's check 
    yy_cp );  
    xnor (z[1], a[0], a[1]);
    or (w1, a[0], a[1]);
    xnor (z[2], a[2], w1);
    and (w2, a[2], a[1]);
    and (w3, a[2], a[0]);
    nor (z[3], w2, w3);
    nor (w4, sel, z[3]);
    nor (w5, sel, z[2]);
    and (w6, sel, z[1]);
    and (w7, sel, z[0]);
    or (out[1], w4, w6);
    or (out[0], w5, w7);
endmodule

And *yy_cp)
 Let's check yy_cp ;0_0And *yy_cp;
```

So here yy_cp is the buffer being read and *yy_cp is the actual character for every pass. If you see at one instant yy_cp has the entire code .. the next moment it is ) 0.. I wonder if it is a problem with the grammar or what?

No this is not a homework problem.

Thanks for all your suggestions..